# LAN connection problem

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, lan

I am running into an issue that my campus LAN connection is not getting connected.I am using Ubuntu 20.04.It was fine 2 days ago but now it shows authentication problem even though i enter correct credential.The LAN connection requires no CA certificate.I just need to enter my credentials.Even after entering correct credentials,it again prompts me for entering password without showing whether password was correct or not.As of password,i am pretty much sure that it is correct.

To diagnose issue, I ran the following command in terminal

> nmtui-connect

it then showed me the available wifi and ethernet connection.But when i tried connecting to ethernet,it says

> Could not activate connection:
> Connection 'Profile 1' is not
> available on device enp2s0
> because device has no carrier

[image]

here Profile 1 is the name for ethernet connection i am using.How can i solve this problem ?Thanks